# How do i make my music bot send embed from a function when song is played?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, distube

So I made music bot and I'm making it work on Discord js v13 and Distube v3(I have been using v12 before). Sadly there are many changes and some of them made me search for solution for hours. If you can help me with this one i may be able to fix the whole bot :D. So here's the **code:https://sourceb.in/BI41NrxFPH**. When song is played i want my bot to send embed but it doesn't send anything. I made lots of changes and got many results like

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

but embed was never sent. If you need some information let me know.

Comment: Firstly don't put link to code, you can embed code here on your question easily.
Secondly add paragraphs in your questions so we can have a better readability. Then show us what edit(s) did you tried to solve your sending problem.
What was the previous working solution with Discord v12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

```
    var playingMessage =  message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1] });
```

Sending messages doesn't ​work as a variant

Try typing

```
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1] });
```

In the last line of the playback function or in the:

```
//function playsongyes(song)  example
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1] });
```

Comment: Could you please explain it more? What playback function?

Comment: In the function where the bot enters the channel, add the code to send the message